# Plot multiple traces in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I started learning R for data analysis and, most importantly, for data visualisation.

Since I am still in the switching process, I am trying to reproduce the activities I was doing with Graphpad Prism or Origin Pro in R. In most of the cases everything was smooth, but I could not find a smart solution for plotting multiple y columns in a single graph.

What I usually get from the softwares I use for data visualisations look like this:

[image]

Each single black trace is a measurement, and I would like to obtain the same plot in R. In Prism or Origin, this will take a single copy-paste in a XY graph.

I exported the matrix of data (one X, which indicates the time, and multiple Y values, which are the traces you see in the image).

I imported my data in R with the following commands:

```
library(ggplot2) #loaded ggplot2

Data <- read.csv("Directory/File.txt", header=F, sep="") #imported data
DF <- data.frame(Data) #transformed data into data frame
```

If I plot my data now, I obtain a series of columns, where the first one (called V1) is the X axis and all the others (V2 to V140) are the traces I want to put on the same graph.

To plot the data, I tried different solutions:

```
ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=DF$V1, y=DF[V2:V140]))+geom_line()+theme_bw() #did not work

plot(DF, xy.coords(x=DF$V1, y=DF$V2:V140)) #gives me an error

plot(DF, xy.coords(x=V1, y=c(V2:V10))) #gives me an error
```

I tried the `matplot`, without success, following the EZH guide:

The code I used is the following: `matplot(x=DF$V1, type="l", lty = 2:100)`

The only solution I found would be to individually plot a command for each single column, but it is a crazy solution. The number of columns varies among my data, and manually enter commands for 140 columns is insane.

What would you suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Here there are also some data attached.[Data: single X, multiple Y](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36889/AP.txt)

Comment: how did you try the matplot() function? could you share the code? and also share a small sample of your data for us to directly work on!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. The data are present in the Dropbox link at the end of the post. I added in the main post the details on the matplot function.

Comment: okay... didn't you also add the y-argument in matplot call? something like
matplot(df[["x"]], y = df[,c(paste0("y",1:5))], type = "l")

Comment: I tried, but it does not seem to work, and I get this error: `Error: unexpected symbol in "matplot(DF[["x"]], y=DF[ ,c(paste0(, 2:5))] type`   What I would like to plot is a single X and all the other Y columns. I can't believe it is so tricky.

Comment: dear, where is the "y" inside the paste() ?

Comment: I am sorry, I also noticed that I forgot a comma. Apparently my data are not vectors.. `Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`

Comment: You may use the following link to do your work
https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-ggplot-with-multiple-lines/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the matplot(). I used a very sample data which has no trend at all. so th eoutput from my code shall look terrible, but my main focus is on the code. Since you have already tried matplot() ,just recheck with below solution if you had done it right!

```
set.seed(100)
df = matrix(sample(1:685765,50000,replace = T),ncol = 100)
colnames(df)=c("x",paste0("y", 1:99))
dt=as.data.frame(df)
matplot(dt[["x"]], y = dt[,c(paste0("y",1:99))], type = "l")
```

Comment: YES! It did work! Still have to polish the line color, size, axes titles, but the output is what I was looking for.  I need more time to understand how to properly use functions in R. Thank you for the help; it is very appreciated in the difficult transition from Prism to R :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot in base `R`, you have to make a plot and add lines one at a time, however that isn't hard to do.

we start by making some sample data. Since the data in the link seemed to all be on the same scale, I will assume your data frame only has `y` values and the x value is stored separately.

```
plotData <- as.data.frame(matrix(sort(rnorm(500)),ncol = 5))
xval <- sort(sample(200, 100))
```

Now we can initialize a plot with the first column.

```
plot(xval, plotData[[1]], type = "l", 
     ylim = c(min(plotData), max(plotData)))
```

- `type = "l"` makes a line plot instead of a scatter plot
- `ylim = c(min(plotData), max(plotData))` makes sure the y-axis will fit all the data.

Now we can add the rest of the values.

`apply(plotData[-1], 2, lines, x = xval)`

- `plotData[-1]` removes the column we already plotted,
- `apply` function with `2` as the second parameter means we want to execute a function on every column,
- `lines` defines the function we are `apply`ing to the columns. `lines` adds a new line to the current plot.
- `x = xval` passes an extra parameter (`x`) to the `lines` function.

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The solution partially worked. My X column is the first column of my DF (not stored separately), and I adapted the code to use it as X in this way: `plot(DF$V1, DF[[2]], type="l")
apply(DF[-2], 2, lines, x=DF$V1)` The plot went out fine, but the first column is plotted as it was an Y [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36889/AP.png

Answer (score 0):

if you wat to plot the data using ggplot2, the data should be transformed to long format;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dat <- read.delim('AP.txt', header = F)

# plotting only first 9 traces
# my rstudio will crach if I plot the full data;
df <- melt(dat[1:10], id.vars = 'V1')

ggplot(df, aes(x = V1, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line()

# if you want all traces to be in same colour, you can use
ggplot(df, aes(x = V1, y = value, group = variable)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Also this solution was brilliant and worked perfectly. Thank you